# MS ACCESS vba select

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a table in MS Access with data that I'm trying to select. The table has a userID in it, so I'm only trying to select info with a particular user ID. What I'm doing though is passing the userID to a form in access, so I want to be able to reference the frm field in my query. When i run this code below it tells me theres too few parameters.

```
dim rs1 as DAO.recordset
strSQL = "Select * from [dbo_tempDetail] where [userID] = [Forms]![frmUserInfo]![txtCLIENTID];"

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, , dbOpenDynamic)

rCount = rs1.RecordCount
```

what is wrong here

EDIT 2

```
strSQL = "Select * from [dbo_tempDetail] where userID = '" & [Forms]![frmUserInfo]![txtClientID] & "' "

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, , dbOpenDynamic)

rCount = rs1.RecordCount
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query criteria based on form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063326/query-criteria-based-on-form-field)

Comment: numeric (int) i'm pulling it from sql server into Access (with link manager) but i'm working out of Access

Comment: thanks, post as answer @hansup sorry Jeeped got it right first!

Comment: No he and YOU got it right, I have data in a tempTable with multiple UserID's - I need to pull data only for a particular ID and edit some of it. Thanks @HansUp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SELECT statement must be a concatenated string using the form value(s). VBA might know what `[Forms]![frmUserInfo]![txtCLIENTID]` is, but the SELECT does not.

```
strSQL = "Select * from [dbo_tempDetail] where [userID] = " & _
             [Forms]![frmUserInfo]![txtCLIENTID] & ";"
'might have to quote the txtCLIENTID value
strSQL = "Select * from [dbo_tempDetail] where [userID] = '" & _
             [Forms]![frmUserInfo]![txtCLIENTID] & "';"
```

Comment: I put it in quotes but its giving me error 3464 "DataType Mismatch in criteria expression" You can see what my query looks like in EDIT 2. Thanks

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes? It doesn't matter whether VBA thinks txtCLIENTID is a string or an int. What matters is that strings get quoted in an SQL SELECT and ints do not.

Comment: it's working with single instance of " " around teh query